# Livecode and Biopac Interface

Tags: interface, livecode

My lab recently purchased the BIOPAC system to measure skin conductance as part of our experiments.

My experiments are normally coded using Livecode.

I need to be able to tell Livecode to automatically score and label digital event marks in the skin conductance responses in the BIOPAC System.

Does anyone have any experience interfacing the BIOPAC system and Livecode? Does anyone have same code they have used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a gadget from "Bonig und KallenBach":

http://www.bkohg.com/serviceusbplus_e.html

This has analog inputs that you could easily configure to measure skin resistance. It comes with a framework for LiveCode, and connects through the USB port.

I have used these in many applications to connect the real world to my computer. All your processing is done in the usual LC way.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no direct Example using Biopac Hardware.
To tinkering with your own software outside AcqKnowledge, you have to purchase BHAPI (MPDEV.dll) from Biopac. The problem is BHAPI only support Windows. not MacOS nor Linux.

Another way is streaming data through AcqKnowledge 5.x. Start acquisition in AcqKnowledge, and you can stream it. Then receive the data stream in livecode and process it.